# Unity can't load System.data.dll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've downloaded the last Unity (2018.1) and changed the scripting runtime version to 4.x.

But I can't find which System.Data.dll I should include in my project (I need it for my System.Data.SQLite library).

If I check in Unity's folders There are a lot of folders in MonoBleedingEdge/lib/mono : 4.0, 4.0-api, 4.5, 4.5.1-api ...

I tried with a few System.Data.dll found in those folders

I always get that "Loading script assembly "Assets/Plugins/System.Data.dll" failed!" when I run my game. Do you know why ? Or is there a possibility to have more details (like version of the dll expected)

Comment: Where did you find System.Data.dll?

Answer (score 1):

### My Weeks Journey:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050951/how-do-i-import-mysql-connector-into-unity-project/52067993#52067993)
- [Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1546955/how-do-i-import-mysql-connector-from-nuget-into-un.html?childToView=1547402#answer-1547402)

### Solution:

It took me a week to finally figure it out...

You need to use:

- I18N.dll
- I18N.West.dll
- I18N.*.dll (Optional, they are region specific)
- System.Data.dll

from C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0

***NOT*** the BleedingEdge path.
Then it will work without errors... confirmed in the latest Unity 2018.2.6f1

Comment: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity worked for me, but I'm using API Compatibility Level .NET 4.x  in Unity 2019.3

Answer (score 0):

What if you try replacing `System.Data` here

`/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2018.1.0b11/Unity.app/Contents/MonoBleedingEdge/lib/mono/unity`

**Note:** I've Unity HUb installed but the path should be similar

Answer (score 0):

The thing that worked for me was following this [Unity Forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/c-compression-zip-missing.577492/page-2) thread and using a csc.rsp as Unity Suggests. You can see my answer there.